# Count by > DATE

Tags: python

How would I do a > expression in a count? For example:

```
# equivalence
l = [1,2,2,3,4]
l.count(2)
2

# greater than date
l = [datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)]
l.count('date is greater than '2014-02-01')
1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> l = [datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0)]
>>> sum(1 for d in l if d > datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0))
1
```

For example the expression:

```
l.count(2)
```

does the same as:

```
sum(1 for v in l if v == 2)
```

But to do what you ask for we need to replace `==` with `>` resulting in the solution presented above.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean values (and expressions) effectively have a numeric value of `0` or `1`, so you could just add a bunch of them up:

```
dates = [datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 31, 0, 0),
         datetime.datetime(2014, 2,  1, 0, 0),
         datetime.datetime(2014, 2,  2, 0, 0)]

cutoff = datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0)
print(sum(d > cutoff for d in dates))  # --> 1
```